# LINQ over XAML Provider

Tags: c#, linq

Is there LINQ provider to access XAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [XAML Toolkit 2009](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/XAML).

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you need it to do? In many cases I'd expect LINQ to XML to work well enough. If you want to be able to find a specific element and then get the object represented by it, that could be trickier - partly due to dependencies etc.

Comment: I know you are *the* Jon Skeet, but shouldn't this be a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: @Natrium: I considered that - but felt that the "LINQ to XML" part could be useful as an answer instead. If the OP expands the question in a way that means it's not a useful answer, I'll delete it.